# Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.7"

Tags: java, android, macos, java-8, java-7

I have been setting my JAVA_HOME to "/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7" on my OSX(El Capitan). After recent update to JDK from jdk1.8.0_66 to jdk1.8.0_91, I get error **Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.7".**

Does anyone know how to still use JVM 1.7 for JAVA_HOME after this update ?

Comment: Where are you getting this error? What application?

Comment: I have to set 1.7 as my JAVA_HOME for my Android app to compile. I get this error from command line